# Hiding tabs when saving a dashboard to Tableau Reader from Tableau Desktop?

Tags: tableau-api

I am planning to share a dashboard using Tableau Reader. I developed the dashboard in Tableau Desktop and have several sheets (that connect to dashboard) that I would like to hide before sharing. I saved the .twb to a .twbx and opened the file and to my surprise the hidden sheets are now visible in Reader. To this point I have not found any solutions or workarounds to this problem.

Can anyone provide some help here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tableau Reader allows user to see everything, including the hidden sheets. The workaround is you can create a calculated field that is always wrong (i.e. 0>0), and apply it to the filter in the sheets you want to hide. Now when user open the Tableau Reader and click the sheets you want to hide, they will see blank sheets. It's not pretty, but that's the easiest way to not show specific sheets.

On your side, you can easily make the sheets visible by removing the filter.